# Migrating Firefox Profile and Settings to Firefox Developer

Tags: firefox, browser

Firefox Developer installs with a completely separate profile and set of preferences by default when the "normal" Firefox is already installed. I've been using the original browser for a few years now, so I would be pleased to know whether there is a way to migrate *everything* from Firefox to Firefox Developer. By everything I mean bookmarks, themes, extensions, `about:config` settings, dictionaries, etc.

The ideal would be keeping both in sync (e.g. installing an extension on one browser also installs it to the other; same for adding bookmarks or changing themes.)

I notice `Mozilla Firefox` and `Firefox Developer Edition` are two separate folders in `C:\Program Files.` Could adding the Firefox Developer EXE and a few accompanying files to the original Firefox browser folder be part of the solution?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please take the quick [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to see how StackExchange Q&A sites differ from the internet forums. Also please see Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how things work. [From Review](https://superuser.com/review/first-questions/1084475)

Comment: Perhaps [Firefox Sync](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/sync/)?

Comment: @harrymc Very interesting option, thank you... I would most probably use this as a last recourse given that it requires signing up for an account, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @harrymc I just checked out this link: https://www.addictivetips.com/web/sync-about-config-preferences-with-firefox-sync/ , and it seems as if an about:config entry must be made for each individual setting to be synced. 

Comment: It's perhaps time for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firefox Sync](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/sync/)
can synchronize bookmarks, passwords, open tabs and more.
It requires the same Firefox sign-in on all the devices.

The article
[How To Sync about:config Preferences With Firefox Sync](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/sync-about-config-preferences-with-firefox-sync/)
lists the browser preferences that are synced:
the new tab page, Do Not Track, telemetry settings and the theme.

To sync other `about:config` settings, each `setting` must be set to be
synced, by adding a new boolean entry named `services.sync.prefs.setting`.
As usually only a few `about:config` settings need to be changed,
this is not a serious problem.

Comment: Additionally to using Firefox Sync, I also copied my profile folder from Firefox to Firefox Dev... Works perfect. Initially, FF Sync did not sync all my extensions, for some unknown reason, but cloning the profile folder fixed this. All my about:config settings seemed to have migrated as well, without the need to make entries for every single setting I wanted to sync!